# Can JPEGs have overviews?

Tags: gdal, jpg

I was a little surprised to see the output of a .jpg file when gdalinfo said it had overviews.

Can jpegs really have overviews or what does this mean? Can they be removed to reduce file size?

```
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
  SOURCE_COLOR_SPACE=YCbCr
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 4912.0)
Upper Right ( 7360.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 7360.0, 4912.0)
Center      ( 3680.0, 2456.0)
Band 1 Block=7360x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 3680x2456, 1840x1228, 920x614
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG
Band 2 Block=7360x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 3680x2456, 1840x1228, 920x614
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG
Band 3 Block=7360x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 3680x2456, 1840x1228, 920x614
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDAL, since version 1.10, can find 2x, 4x, and 8x overviews directly from the JPEG encoded data. There is something about the theory in this blog post:

http://erouault.blogspot.fi/2014/04/advanced-jpeg-in-tiff-uses-in-gdal.html

Those overviews belong to JPEG encoding and therefore they do not take any extra space nor can they be deleted. Before GDAL 1.10 they were just not utilized at all.